# .NET Reflector error: No disassembled code

Tags: .net, reflector

I've been using .NET Reflector for awhile but I've just recently switched machines and I've reinstalled. However, when I try to disassemble code now, the Disassembler window just shows up as blank.

Here's a screenshot where I'm trying to disassemble a TimeSpan Member:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1678/36689859iz7.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/1678/36689859iz7.png)

Comment: Is this the same for all properties, methods and fields?  I'm sure you need more than this, but FYI: public const long TicksPerSecond = 0x989680L;

Comment: Yes it's the same for all assemblies, whether they're part of the BCL or not.

Comment: reflector version? is it latest? .net frameworks installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem. It seems to have been caused when I installed Internet Explorer 7, and disappeared after I restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, don't know what was happening but it seems to have fixed itself.